# android app, Java - Overflow Menu Error and it's not displaying in the action bar

Tags: java, android

I did not expect an error to come up but the 3-dot ActionBar menu is not displaying and I am getting an unexpected error. I am not sure where I went wrong in my code.

Please help,
thanks in advance!

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.it5.foothillers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Display app icon in the ActionBar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void buttonClick() {

        startActivity(new Intent("it5.foothillers.news"));
    }

    private void button2Click() {
        startActivity(new Intent("it5.foothillers.sports"));
    }

    private void button3Click() {
        startActivity(new Intent("it5.foothillers.events"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                buttonClick();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                button2Click();
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                button3Click();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add setHasOptionsMenu(true);

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 onCreateOptionsMenu methods. Remove the last 2, you only need the first one with inflater. Also, Override the onOptionsItemSelected method to control the actions.

Comment: use app:showAsAction="ifRoom" in your menu.xml, under item

Comment: Then try app:showAsAction="always". Also make sure you added this line : xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" under the one with xmlns:android. Also, Clean your project after. If it doesn't work, provide you menu.xml code and the editted java code in the main question.